# What are the most common bad practices regarding control value accessor in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular-forms, controlvalueaccessor

I'm implementing a control value accessor to integrate it with my angular form.

Is it valid/proper to pass a certain type of object in it or is recommended to work with primitives when using angular forms?

Object to pass as a FormControl:

```
{ id: number; foo: string; }
```

Is it a bad practice to transform this object (in control value accessor class)? Or should I transform it on a higher level, when I prepare payload for a, let's say, post request?

I'm looking for good and bad practices regarding control value accessor implementations. Most of the stuff I've read talks just about how to implement it.

Comment: If you have type safety, use it. It will save a lot of headaches when debugging. Declaring an interface for that object shouldn't be that time consuming

Comment: If you don't want change "foo" in your control, not pass the whole object (use a Input() to pass the value). Futhermore, your dataObject must not contain this propertie. Otherwise is perfectly normal

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a bad practice to do so : if you look at [the API of the control value accessor](https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor#properties), you will see the `compareWith` function, used to track down items equality when using non primitive values.

But even though it's not a bad practice, you should consider thinking before implementing it. Your values are objects with two properties. Objects are usually form groups, or if not, their properties are bound with ngModel. But not the full object.

In your case, you only have an ID and a value. For that, you could use a simple select input, because the control might not be complicated enough to make a control value accessor.

To sum it up : it's not a bad practice to use non-primitive values, but it's always complicated to make a control value accessor, so think about an easier way to do it before doing it.